# How do I display candidate's full name inside job application which is inside job offer from API response

Tags: angular

`Components.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['jobId'];
this.jobService.findJobById(this.id)
.subscribe((data: JobOffer) =>{
  this.job = data;
  console.log(data);
});
```

I'm using Angular's drag and drop module:

```html
<div cdkDropListGroup>
&nbsp;
<div class="example-container" *ngFor="let items of job.phaseT.items; index as i">
  <h3>{{items.phaseItem}} PHASE</h3>
  
            <div
            cdkDropList id="{{items.id}}" 
            [cdkDropListData]="items.phaseItem"
            class="item-list" 
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedTo"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let job of job.jobApplications" cdkDrag  [cdkDragData]="job">
                <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let candidate of job.candidate" cdkDrag  [cdkDragData]="job">
                   {{candidate.fullname}} --   {{job.appliedDate | date}} -
                  <button class="button btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/candidateProfile']">View Profile</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what i tried so far, I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

I also tried accessing it using this:

```
<div class="example-container" *ngFor="let candidate of job.jobApplications.candidate;">
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it? Assuming you've successfully made the request, it seems like just basic array/object access.

Comment: I have edited my question , up top is the whole object and below is jobApplications array., i tried doing this :   *ngFor="let job of job.jobApplications" then *ngFor="let candidate of job.candidate" then {{candidate.fullname}} and it says Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: This is **code**. Post text, not screenshots. Give a proper [mre].

Comment: I have edited it , sorry for the bad format , i hope it's more clear now

Comment: Please re-read the linked help center article. This is not something we can run to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jobApplications` is an array, which is iterable, so `*ngFor` will work. `job.candidate` is an object which can be accessed directly by property e.g `job.candidate.fullName` or iterating over obj candidate's properties using `keyvalue` pipe.

```html
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let job of jobApplications" cdkDrag  [cdkDragData]="job">
   {{job?.candidate?.fullname}} --   {{job?.appliedDate | date}} -
  <button class="button btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/candidateProfile']">View Profile</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm , thanks Joosep for the answer and the clear explaining

Answer (score 1):

Inside your **component.ts**:

```
export class YourComponent {
  title = 'YourTitle';
  name= '';

  constructor(private yourService: yourService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getName();
  }
  
  getName() {
    this.yourService.getApplicantName().subscribe(
     (data: any) => {
       this.name = data.jobApplications[0].candidate.fullName;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And in your **component.html**:

```
<h1>Full name: {{ name }} </h1>
```

Make sure you adapt my solution to your code. This will probably won't work because you have shown nothing of your code, but I think it will be simple to adapt.
If you are not using any service, just call the method instead the service.

Comment: Just added above screenshots of my component and html

Comment: As I see, you are doing it correctly. Just get into the data as I answered and you will be good to go

Comment: Is there another way instead of doing it inside my method ? can't i just access it directly through ngFor ?

Comment: You could do it that way, yes

Comment: Can u show me an example on my data ?